# Is there a way to see JavaScript frames (not just call stack)? in Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm interested in seeing Tail call optimization (TCO) and things like that. In Chrome debugger, I only see actual call stack but not the real frames so I don't know how to see if my code is actually TCO in debugger.

I want to visually see the difference in frames used (or not used) for the following two examples:

```
  // Not optimized recursive function 
  function factorial(x) {
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x * factorial(x-1); // (A)
    }
}



// TCO version
function factorial(n) {
     return facRec(n, 1);
}

function facRec(x, acc) {
    if (x <= 1) {
    return acc;
  } else {
    return facRec(x-1, x*acc); // (A)
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's implemented in Chrome? It's not. TCO is [disabled and not developed currently](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4698)

Comment: I have read many blogs saying that it's working in ES6 and if we use "use strict" mode, so I thought it's already implemented, but may be not!

Comment: I see. The thing is, TCO was enabled for some time until it became clear the implementation is incorrect. Anyway, there might be command line flags to enable internal V8 stuff like js low level info, try googling. All I know (after reading some of V8 devs blog) these flags work for node.js.